# LED Dimmable 2 of the 8 turn off when others are dim

Tags: led, dimmer

So I just had [Integrated LED Recessed Retrofit Ceiling Light Fixtures](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-RL-5-in-and-6-in-White-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Retrofit-Ceiling-Light-Fixture-910-Lumens-90-CRI-3500K-Bright-White-RL560WH9935R/205548253) installed on a [Lutron Toggler 150-watt Double Pole 3-way White Toggle Indoor Dimmer](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Lutron-Toggler-150-watt-Double-Pole-3-way-White-Toggle-Indoor-Dimmer/3376148) (rated for LED lights).

When the dimmer is set to a certain lever on low, to turn off while the remaining 6 are dim but they're still on.

Any idea what the issue is? Thanks guys!

Comment: Sounds like production tolerances.

Comment: Poor design. Inappropriate use of a dimmer. Voting to close as you should read the data sheets and confirm whether this is a problem and buy from reputable sources that provide good data.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Jay, but you're on an Engineering forum so you need to be precise with your details. Please edit your question to explain what a "can light" is and supply a link to a datasheet. (2) Similarly, we would need to know at a minimum what type of dimmer it is. (3) Can you provide any voltage measurements?

Comment: Here are the lights i'm using. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halo-RL-5-in-and-6-in-White-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Retrofit-Ceiling-Light-Fixture-910-Lumens-90-CRI-3500K-Bright-White-RL560WH9935R/205548253

And here is the dimmer, hope this helps!
https://www.lowes.com/pd/Lutron-Toggler-150-watt-Double-Pole-3-way-White-Toggle-Indoor-Dimmer/3376148

Comment: Hi, Jay. This information belongs in the *question* so that it's all in one place. Highlight the word you want to link and press the 'link' button to enter the URL.

Comment: Dimmable- standard 120-Volt electronic low-voltage dimmer is recommended for best performance (see buying guide for dimmer compatibility chart) --- Did you pick a dimmer from the compatibility chart?

Comment: @Transistor better? ☺  I had no idea what a "can" was either.

Comment: @Andyaka "Poor design. Inappropriate use of a dimmer."  I thought we were supposed to be nice to newbies☺

Comment: Being honest and expressing my opinion is being nice.

Answer (score 1):

Dimmers work by varying the trigger angle of the mains.

[image]

*Figure 1. Phase or trigger angle control of AC mains. Source: [Dimmers for LEDs](https://lednique.com/bulbs/dimmers-for-leds/).*

How the bulb responds to this depends on its internal circuitry. The incandescent lamps were simply a hot resistance wire and they worked fine. LED mains lamps have a wide variety of circuit configurations - some of which work well with dimmers and some that don't.

[image]

*Figure 2. Some of the cheap LED mains lamps use a capacative voltage dropper to reduce the voltage and limit the current to the lamps. These generally work OK on a standard dimmer.*

[image]

*Figure 3. A slightly more complex version has a smoothing capacitor, C2, added.*

If a smooting capacitor such as C2 is included after the rectifier then the dimmer won’t appear to do anything until the control is adjusted below 50%. This is because the capacitor charges up fully at peak mains even if it hasn’t been on up to 90° into the half-cycle. (See Figure 1.) From 90° to 180° the peak voltage drops so the lamp will dim in proportion.

> Any idea what the issue is?

It is most likely a minor difference in components due to production spread in the various components of the lamps. Unfortunately the subject of dimming has got a lot more complex since the conversion from incandescent to LED lamps. Unless you can source lamps designed to work with a specific dimmer the results will be a bit hit and miss.

I have written a little more on the topic in the article linked in Figure 1.

Comment: Oh yeah, now he'll know which dimmer to buy. ☺

Comment: I don't understand your comment and don't want you to be Misunderstood. Can you clarify?

Comment: And I even added the smiley face so I would not be misunderstood (oh lord, please don't let me be...).   I think you may be way over this guy's head.  I don't think he wants to know how a dimmer works and likely would not understand if he did.  And I have a warped sense of humor.   And I have been drinking today.☺☺  Your answer is good.  +1